# All possible combinations (sequential)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am wondering what an efficient approach to the following question would be:

Suppose I have three characters in group 1 and two characters in group 2:

```
group_1 = c("X", "Y", "Z")
group_2 = c("A", "B")
```

Clearly, the "all" possible combinations for group_1 and group_2 are given by:

```
group_1_combs = data.frame(X = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
                           Y = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1),
                           Z = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1))
group_2_combs = data.frame(A = c(0,1,0,1),
                           B = c(0,0,1,1))
```

My question is the following:

(1) How do I go from `group_1` to `group_1_combs` efficiently (given that the character vector might be large).

(2) How do I do an "all possible" combinations of each row of `group_1_combs` and `group_2_combs`? Specifically, I want a "final" data.frame where each row of `group_1_combs` is "permuted" with every row of `group_2_combs`. This means that the final data.frame would have 8 x 4 rows (since there are 8 rows in `group_1_combs` and 4 rows in `group_2_combs`) and 5 columns `(X,Y,Z,A,B)`.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you tagged with data.table, might want to try a variant of jblood's answer using `CJ`: `group_1_combs <- do.call(CJ, setNames(rep(list(c(0, 1)), length(group_1)), group_1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `expand.grid` and `merge`:

Question 1:

```
group_1_combs <- expand.grid(setNames(rep(list(c(0, 1)), length(group_1)), group_1))
group_2_combs <- expand.grid(setNames(rep(list(c(0, 1)), length(group_2)), group_2))
```

Question 2:

```
> merge(group_1_combs, group_2_combs)
   X Y Z A B
1  0 0 0 0 0
2  1 0 0 0 0
3  0 1 0 0 0
4  1 1 0 0 0
5  0 0 1 0 0
6  1 0 1 0 0
7  0 1 1 0 0
...
```

Or you can go directly to the merged data.frame:

```
group_12 <- c(group_1, group_2)
expand.grid(setNames(rep(list(c(0, 1)), length(group_12)), group_12))
```